# Recommended approach to using a common View across controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a developed a common "index container" view which uses a partial View. Many controllers use this, and at present a container view exists for each controller as per normal MVC convention which is a bit silly.

I would like to call common view, a possible idea may be:

```
return View("~/Views/Shared/_Container.cshtml");
```

Perhaps there is a better approach?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a slight issue in that I am using "Areas" and wish to locate the shared View in the Root Shared View folder. Just discovered this issue. So because of this I may need to state the full path????

Comment: that is how we do it.  for areas just add areas/areaname/views...

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that one has to be explicit when using areas? In my case I am not seeking the view in an area, rather the other way round ie an Area Controller is trying to use a root shared view. If I try not being explicit, it will just look in the Area Shared View folder.

Comment: just make sure the path matches,  for Url.ActionLink we add area = "" if we are looking something in the root folder

Comment: OK thanks for this. I am using "return View" as I am in an Action and within View() one cannot specify area as in new {area=""} which would take you to root, if you were using "Redirect". So the only option is to provide an explict path as far as I understand.

Comment: I agree,  that is the only way that I am aware of doing it